# Did Hermione have an eidetic memory?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

Did Hermione have what we would consider [Eidetic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory)? I think she didn't, because I think there's somewhere in the books where she says that she forgot something.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No.  Her memory is very good, she has near-total recall, but it isn't perfect.

For instance, in *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* Hermione says, "I'm trying to remember how to kill it" about the Devil's Snare.

If she had an eidectic memory, she'd have remembered what Professor Sprout said word-for-word and wouldn't have gotten only half of it ('likes dark and damp').

Comment: [Wikipedia] : There are a number of individuals with extraordinary memory who have been labeled eidetickers, but many use mnemonics and other, non-eidetic memory enhancing exercises.
I think "pure" Eidetic memory is impossible.

Comment: Related (and a shameless plug): [Is photographic memory possible?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/4564/864)

Comment: @Xaltar - I don't think it's impossible, see savants like Kim Peek. I think it's extremely rare, and given that it often accompanies some brain development or mental development impairment (such as autism), that it is likely a function that is along a slightly different evolutionary path, one that general humanity may or may not get to.

Comment: Anyway, @Xaltar would probably say magic is also impossible, so his comment is irrelevant to HP :)

Answer (score 0):

Hermione explicitly states that she cannot remember something:

**Chamber of Secrets Chapter 9**

> Hermione emerged from between the bookshelves.
>
> She looked irritable and at last seemed ready to talk to them.
>
> “All the copies of Hogwarts, A History have been taken out,” she said,
>   sitting down next to Harry and Ron. “And there’s a two-week waiting
>   list. I wish I hadn’t left my copy at home, but I couldn’t fit it in
>   my trunk with all the Lockhart books.”
>
> “Why do you want it?” said Harry.
>
> “The same reason everyone else wants it,” said Hermione, “to read up
>   on the legend of the Chamber of Secrets.”
>
> “What’s that?” said Harry quickly.
>
> “That’s just it. I can’t remember,” said Hermione, biting her lip.
>   “And I can’t find the story anywhere else — ”